# Selenium does not work (error) when running via nohup on the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

When I run the script on a local PC, everything works, but when I run the script on the server (nohup), errors. The driver version is the same as the program version. python3.10

Errors:

```
NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.100)`
or WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools) (Session info: headless chrome=110.0.5481.100)
```

When trying `driver.window_handles` (to find out how many windows), another error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools) (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.100).
```

Maybe someone has encountered or knows what the problem is?

Code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
options.add_argument('--headless')  
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')  
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36")   
loc = os.getcwd()
serv = Service("%s/chromedriver" % loc)
os.chmod("%s/chromedriver" % loc, 755) driver: webdriver.Chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=serv) driver.get("any_link")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same type of error. Local PC works fine, remote or virtual works fine until I disconnect from the machine. I think this error has to do with the user session on the remote machine, when disconnected or screen saver kicks in the chromedriver loose connection with the browser instance it controls.
the Fix that worked for me: switch the sleep and screen mode to never (if windows box).